# Preventing Sphinx from turning :var:s into hyperlinks

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My package documentation includes several [`:var foo:` fields](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists) where `foo` happens to have the same name as a tangentially-related object elsewhere in the package, and Sphinx insists on rendering these fields as hyperlinks to the other objects (or even as hyperlinks to the official Python docs after I added [intersphinx linking](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html)).  How do I tell Sphinx to not turn any `:var:`s into hyperlinks?